# Insert "do_action" into an array at a specific index (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, splice

Has anyone ever been able to insert the output from do_action into an array at a specific index? For example, if you have the array and function below:

```
$myarr = array(1,2,3,4);

 my_function(){
  return 4 + 4;
}
```

I'm trying to do:

```
array_splice($myarr, 2, 0, do_action('my_function'););
```

And have it output:

```
[1, 2, 8, 3, 4]
```

I'm trying to integrate something like this in a wordpress page, and it breaks my entire page.

Answer (score 1):

If that's your exact code then the problem is here

```
array_splice($myarr, 2, 0, do_action('my_function'););
```

correct line is

```
array_splice($myarr, 2, 0, my_function());
```

Comment: Additionally, the `function` keyword is missing from the beginning of the my_function declaration.